# How to change batch size of batchblock dynamically during runtime?

Tags: c#, concurrency, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow, batching

I have a batch block in tpl dataflow and have several target blocks linked to the batch block. However, the number of target blocks changes dynamically and thus the size of the batches. Problem is that the batch size must be supplied at the initialization of the batchblock and I dont see a way to adjust it later on. Any ideas how to get around this? Is the only way to unlink (dispose all links to batchblock and from batchblock), re-initialize the batch block with a new batch size and then link again? I could do that but how to ensure that old batches and new batches are not get all mixed up?

For example if I had 2 transform blocks stream to batch block and now have an additional transform block and want to increase batch size to 3, how do I make sure that all previous batches prior to the increase were processed to ensure synched behavior? Point is that all transform blocks get the exact identical item and the outputs of those transform blocks should be batched in the way that only those outputs are batched that match identical inputs.

Here a sample how I want it to be:

Constant stream of ints to transform blocks:
1,2,3, [point where batch size is increased],4,5,...

Let transform blocks output what they got in like 1 => 1

So batchblock should output like this :
[1,1], [2,2], [3,3], [change of batch size], [4,4,4], [5,5,5],...

Here my current code:

```
public class Test
{
    private Stopwatch watch;

    private BroadcastBlock<List<InputObject>> tempBCB;
    private BatchBlock<Tuple<List<InputObject>, Dictionary<int, IntermediateObject>>> batchBlock;
    private TransformBlock<Tuple<List<InputObject>, Dictionary<int, IntermediateObject>>[], List<FinalObject>> transformBlock;
    private ActionBlock<List<FinalObject>> justToFlushTransformBlock;

    private CoreLogic core1;
    private CoreLogic core2;

    public Test()
    {
        tempBCB = new BroadcastBlock<List<InputObject>>(input => input);

        //here batch size = 2
        batchBlock = new BatchBlock<Tuple<List<InputObject>,Dictionary<int,IntermediateObject>>>(2, new GroupingDataflowBlockOptions { Greedy = false });

        transformBlock = new TransformBlock<Tuple<List<InputObject>,Dictionary<int,IntermediateObject>>[],List<FinalObject>>(array =>
        {
            List<InputObject> inputObjects = array[0].Item1;
            List<FinalObject> ret = inputObjects.ConvertAll(x => new FinalObject(x));

            foreach (var tuple in array)
            {
                //iterate over each individual object
                foreach (var dictionary in tuple.Item2)
                {
                    ret[dictionary.Key].outputList.Add(dictionary.Value);
                }
            }

            return ret;
        }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded });

        justToFlushTransformBlock = new ActionBlock<List<FinalObject>>(list =>
            {
                //just in order to accept items from the transformBlock output queue
            });

        //Generate 2 CoreLogic objects
        core1 = new CoreLogic();
        core2 = new CoreLogic();

        //linking
        tempBCB.LinkTo(core1.transformBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
        tempBCB.LinkTo(core2.transformBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

        core1.transformBlock.LinkTo(batchBlock);
        core2.transformBlock.LinkTo(batchBlock);

        batchBlock.LinkTo(transformBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

        transformBlock.LinkTo(justToFlushTransformBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        const int numberChunks = 30;

        watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        for (int j = 1; j <= numberChunks; j++)
        {
            int collectionSize = 10000 * j;

            List<InputObject> collection = new List<InputObject>(collectionSize);
            for (int i = 0; i < collectionSize; i++)
            {
                collection.Add(new InputObject(i));
            }

            tempBCB.Post(collection);
        }

        tempBCB.Complete();

        Task.WhenAll(core1.transformBlock.Completion, core2.transformBlock.Completion).ContinueWith(_ =>
            {
                batchBlock.Complete();
            });

        transformBlock.Completion.Wait();

        watch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time (in milliseconds): " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class CoreLogic
{
    private Random rand;
    public TransformBlock<List<InputObject>, Tuple<List<InputObject>, Dictionary<int, IntermediateObject>>> transformBlock;

    public CoreLogic()
    {
        const int numberIntermediateObjects = 10000;

        transformBlock = new TransformBlock<List<InputObject>, Tuple<List<InputObject>, Dictionary<int, IntermediateObject>>>(input =>
        {
            //please ignore the fact that `input` is not utilized here, the point is to generate a collection of IntermediateObject and return

            Dictionary<int, IntermediateObject> ret = new Dictionary<int, IntermediateObject>();
            for (int i = 0; i < numberIntermediateObjects; i++)
            {
                IntermediateObject value = new IntermediateObject(i);

                ret.Add(i, value);
            }

            var tuple = new Tuple<List<InputObject>, Dictionary<int, IntermediateObject>>(input, ret);

            return tuple;
        });
    }
}

public class InputObject : ICloneable
{
    public int value1 { get; private set; }

    public InputObject(int value)
    {
        this.value1 = value;
    }

    object ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        return Clone();
    }

    public InputObject Clone()
    {
        return (InputObject)this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}

public class IntermediateObject
{
    public int value1 { get; private set; }

    public IntermediateObject(int value)
    {
        this.value1 = value;
    }
}

public class FinalObject
{
    public InputObject input { get; private set; }
    public List<IntermediateObject> outputList;

    public FinalObject(InputObject input)
    {
        this.input = input;

        this.outputList = new List<IntermediateObject>();
    }
}

public static class Cloning
{
    public static List<TValue> CloneListCloneValues<TValue>(List<TValue> original) where TValue : ICloneable
    {
        List<TValue> ret = new List<TValue>(original.Count);

        foreach (TValue entry in original)
        {
            ret.Add((TValue)entry.Clone());
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: I too, want to know answer to this, but in the meantime, wouldn't it be possible to either have couple BatchBlocks with different sizes laying around and just switch between them? I'm gonna give that a try. Or another way would be to Complete existing batch and in the continuation reinstantiate the new batch with the new size and assign it to the same variable.

Comment: @Dimitri, I am afraid the solution is gonna be a bit more complex. You can't just have several batch blocks "laying around" because even you exchange one for the other, item flow is majorly interrupted if you dont make sure that the queues are empty, links are disposed, and new links re-established.

Comment: The question is *why*?  I can only see this making sense if you are spinning up action blocks with different *actions*.  Is this what you're doing?

Comment: @casperOne, no the real issue is that the framework does not allow batch size to be adjusted dynamically. If the size could be changed during runtime then batchBlock would simply wait until it gets the new m -> n amount of items to build arrays of those items, its just not provided for although imho it should be. Same issue with join blocks. At the moment the framework only allows for 2 or 3 (forgot) different targetBlocks to be linked to joinBlock which is definitely not optimal. I look for a way around this.

Comment: I think the main reason this isn't provided is that you basically can't do it safely. When you change the batch size, the old transform blocks could still be processing old items, so you might get something like [3,3,4]. How are you going to make sure that doesn't happen? Are you willing to make the batch block less general, so that it would accept only something like `IObjectWithId` and then you could tell it “from id 4 up, create batches of 3”?

Comment: yes something less general would work as well. The number of target blocks supplying batchblock with items is known at all times. i am working on couple ideas but have not found anything satisfactory. if you got ideas those would be very welcome. i agree its not trivial to change batch size during runtine hence my posting this question ;-)